# cdf induced by a cdf

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $(E,\Sigma, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, and $X: E\to \mathbb{R}$ a random variable. $F$ is the cdf of $X$. Define a new random variable $Y:=F(X)$. What is the cdf of $Y$?

Comment: You need to assign a probability to $\mathbb{R}$ first. On the other hand, something interesting happens when you consider the random variable $F(X)$, where $X$ is your random variable- if I recall correctly, $F(X)$ ought to be uniformly distributed. That result has applications in scientific computing, since random number generators are typically used to compute uniform distributions; therefore computing $F^{-1}$ will allow you to turn a uniform distribution into any desired one.

Comment: @user65018: does the revision made to your question agree with your original intent or does the revision basically change the intent?

Comment: @user65018 You might want to answer the query formulated in the last comment above. Failing to do so for 10 days although you are connected to the site strikes me as rather odd.

Answer (score 1):

If $F$ is continuous, then $Y$ is distributed uniformly on $[0,1]$. This is due to
$$P(Y\leq u) = P(F(X)\leq u) = P(F^{\leftarrow}(F(X)) \leq F^{\leftarrow}(u)) = P(X\leq F^{\leftarrow}(u)) = F(F^{\leftarrow}(u)) = u
$$ for any $u\in[0,1]$, where $F^{\leftarrow}$ denotes the generalized inverse of $F$. Note that continuity is essential for the steps made above.

Comment: This is interesting: you suggest a complete modification of the question, this gets accepted by a user (?) and by Community (??) 2 minutes later, and you post an answer 4 minutes later... Et voilà!

Comment: I don't really see how I made a COMPLETE modification to the question. I just formulated the question in a more precise way. What is interesting about me posting an answer to a question that I think i understood and I know the answer to?

Comment: No. Compare "What is the CDF of $F$ interpreted as a random variable on $\mathbb R$?" to "What is the CDF of $F(X)$?"

Comment: Now that you say it. It's a confusing initial formulation though, which doesn't make much sense as it is. Why would he mention the underlying random variable... Anyway, I think I should delete the answer then and revert the changes.

Still, what is so interesting about the facts that you listed above?

Comment: The swiftness, obviously.

Comment: I didn't know I have to let some time pass in order to make another action, so I don't seem suspicious of being...(?) whatever. Thanks for the hint.